# VBA копирование только значений столбцов на другой лист

Tags: excel, vba

Не могу сообразить куда дописать, чтобы копировались только значения найденных столбцов (чтобы ни формат, ни ширина столбцов не попали на нужный лист).

```
Sub Чел()
    Dim currColumn As Object
    Dim mstr As String

    With Worksheets("ППП")
        For I = 1 To 37
            mstr = Array("План", "Факт", и так далее 37 значений)(I - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Worksheets("ЧЧЧ").Columns(I)
        Next I
    End With
    Set currColumn = Nothing
    Sheets("ЧЧЧ").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может, обойдемся без медленной работы с листом? Обработка в массивах:

```
Sub Чел2()
    ' объявляем переменные'
    Dim aData(), aHead(), aRes()
    Dim lRw As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, p As Long

    With Worksheets("ППП")
        aData = .UsedRange.Value ' данные листа в массив'
        aHead = Array("План", "Факт", ...) ' еще один массив - заголовки'
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count ' количество строк пользовательского диапазона'
        ReDim aRes(1 To lRw, 1 To UBound(aHead) + 1) ' определяем размерность массива выгрузки'
    End With

    For j = 0 To UBound(aHead) ' проходим в цикле по массиву заголовков'
        For p = 1 To UBound(aData, 2) ' в цикле ищем заголовок в первой строке данных'
            If aData(1, p) = aHead(j) Then ' если заголовок совпал'
                For i = 1 To lRw: aRes(i, j + 1) = aData(i, p): Next i ' записываем данные столбца в массив выгрузки'
                Exit For
            End If
        Next p
    Next j

    With Worksheets("ЧЧЧ")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lRw, UBound(aRes, 2)).Value = aRes ' выгружаем полученные данные на лист'
        .Activate ' переходим на лист'
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Прошлый макрос я хоть как-то понимал, тут совсем непонятно)

Comment: Убрал мелкие неточности, добавил комментарии

Comment: Спасибо) да основная проблема, что я не знаю синтаксис, в прошлом я разобрался, чтото повторить могу и поправить, а это как вообще другой язык) буду разбираться. Работает заметно быстрее старого варианта)

Comment: Наберите в поиске *VBA массивы*

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
.Columns(currCell.Column).Copy 

Worksheets("ЧЧЧ").Columns(I).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: в дополненной строке выдает error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error